# Spring Boot rest-service shutdown when execute Cucumber test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, integration

I made a rest service using Spring Boot 2 and Cucumber IO 5.7.0 with one endpoint just to execute the cucumber test.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")

public class IntegrationTestController {
@PostMapping("/integration")
public void runCucumber(){
    try {

        Main.main(new String[]{"--glue",
                "pnc/aop/integration", // the package which contains the glue classes
                "src/main/resources/features/healthcheck.feature"});

    } catch (Throwable ex) {

        log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());

    }
}
}
```

As you can see I execute the `Cucumber Main` to execute the steps

```
Feature: Checking all health
  Scenario: Localhost is up
    When When 'localhost:8080/actuator/heatlth' is called
    And Response is UP
```

The definition is this

```
public class HealCheckSteps extends SpringIntegrationTest {

private Health response;


@When("When {string} is called")
public void whenHealthCheckIsCalled(String url) {

    response = checkStatus(url);

}

@And("Response is UP")
public void andReponseIsUp() {

    Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatus().getCode(), "UP");

}
}
```

And

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class SpringIntegrationTest {


protected RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

public SpringIntegrationTest() {

    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

}

public Health checkStatus(String url) {

    try {
        JsonNode response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonNode.class);

        if (response.get("status").asText().equalsIgnoreCase("UP")) {

            return Health.up().build();

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        return Health.down(ex).build();
    }

    return Health.down().build();

}
}
```

Thie setup works, so I can execute a POST to that endpoitn and execute the cucumber test, but 
the service shutdown

```
    1 Scenarios (1 passed)
2 Steps (2 passed)
0m1.454s


2020-05-10 23:58:53.822  INFO 43182 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-10 23:58:53.822  INFO 43182 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want to prevent that but I don't know how

Comment: `Main.main` calls `System.exit`. Try `Main.run` instead.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje it need a ClassLoader
public static byte run(String[] argv, ClassLoader classLoader) {

Comment: That should not stop you. Look at the implementation of `Main.main`.

Comment: It works, add it as a answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Main.main` calls `System.exit`. Try `Main.run` instead.

```
io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(argv, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```

Comment: Main is depracted for cucumber-io 5.7.0, any other option?

Comment: What does the java doc tell you about the deprecation? What does the logging tell you?

Comment: No java doc inside :(

Comment: You should download it.